# How to update the files on Amazon EC2 without using command line

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Right now there is an apache server in EC2,

the approach of update is:

**first , using filezilla with SFTP to upload file to /home/ec2-user folder**

**then , using openPutty to put command line to replace the file**

**e.g. sudo cp /home/ec2-user/test.php /var/www/html/project/**

It is not so straight forward .

I tried in filezilla using the link /var/www/html/ but I only have permission to download file.

So, the question is , are there any more convinent way (e.g. Any GUI tools similar to file explorer if SSH is necessary)?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried WinSCP? It's an open source free SSH client for Windows

Comment: not yet. just google it and found it looks like filezilla , great suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyberduck comes With an easy to use interface, connect to FTP (File Transfer Protocol), SFTP (SSH Secure File Transfer), WebDAV (Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning), Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage and Rackspace Cloud Files.

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en)

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP is an open source free SSH client for Windows that has an easy to use GUI for SSH file transfers and can be configured to work with AWS EC2.

WinSCP is SFTP client, SCP client, FTPS client and FTP client integrated into one software program for file transfer to FTP server or secure SFTP server.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_ssh_client_for_windows for more information and download.